# Parsing and storing the json output of a curl command in bash

Tags: bash, curl, jq

I have five `cURL` statements that work fine by themselves and am trying to put them together in a bash script.  Each `cURL` statement relies on a variable generated from a `cuRL` statement executed before it.  I'm trying to figure out the smartest way to go about this.  Here is the first cURL statement;

```
curl -i -k -b sessionid -X POST https://base/resource -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Authorization: PS-Auth key=keyString; runas=userName; pwd=[password]" -d "{\"AssetName\":\"apiTest\",\"DnsName\":\"apiTest\",\"DomainName\":\"domainNameString\",\"IPAddress\":\"ipAddressHere\",\"AssetType\":\"apiTest\"}"
```

This works fine, it produces this output;

```
{"WorkgroupID":1,"AssetID":57,"AssetName":"apiTest","AssetType":"apiTest","DnsName":"apiTest","DomainName":"domainNameString","IPAddress":"ipAddressHere","MacAddress":null,"OperatingSystem":null,"LastUpdateDate":"2017-10-30T15:18:05.67-07:00"}
```

However, in the next `cURL` statement, I need to use the integer from `AssetID` in order to execute it.  In short, how can I take the `AssetID` value and store it to a variable to be used in the next statement?  In total, I'll be using 5 `cURL` statements and they rely on values generated in the preceeding statement to execute.  Any insight on how is appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Download and install `jq` which is like `sed` for `JSON` data. You can use it to slice and filter and map and transform structured data with the same ease that `sed`, `awk`, `grep` does for unstructured data. Remember to replace `'...'` with your actual `curl` arguments

```
curl '...' | jq --raw-output '.AssetID'
```

and to store it in a variable use command-substitution syntax to run the command and return the result.

```
asset_ID=$( curl '...' | jq --raw-output '.AssetID' )
```

In the `curl` command, drop the `-i` flag to output only the `JSON` data without the header information.

Comment: that worked!  Thank you, Inian, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: The suggested edit queue is full, but I'm sure many people are suggesting to change the part like `< curl command >` to be a little clearer since many people are reading the < and > symbols as part of the valuable code, but it is actually used here to show like this 
`<curl command> |  jq` which is read very differently than `< curl command > | jq`.

Comment: @Urasquirrel: True, modified! thanks